# How to add custom error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have view that is showing all validation errors on login and it is working just fine, however I would like to add another validation error if email/pass is not correct. I've followed some information but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
));

if ($validation->fails()) {
    // These errors work just fine and are showing
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validation);
}

// .. some code to check user credentials etc..

// Here I want to imitate validation error
// I don't even have "workaround" on my form so it should always be null
// But the errors won't show
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('workaround' => 'required'), array('workaround' => 'Wrong email and/or password.'));
$validation->fails();
return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validation);
```

View

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="errrors">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
            <li>{{ $message }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: You can add custom validation rules by extending the validator. See http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules for explanation.

Comment: @JackPoint It would be a lot easier if I could just create validator that is not going to pass. I need to perform additional tasks where username/pass are not valid.

Comment: What exactely are you trying to achieve here? Maybere there is a more elegant way, because I see no sense in validating an additional form when the input is does not pass the validator

Comment: If the validator doesn't passes, there must be an error message in the validator. Whats your code to show the error?

Comment: Does `var_dump($errors)` tell you there are errors?

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat I want to imitate validation that is never going to pass with a custom error message. I have got it working now but the message is `The workaround field is required.` instead of what I wrote there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message here is for the validator `workaround`. I think you expect it is for the field.

```php
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('workaround' => 'required'), array('workaround' => 'Wrong email and/or password.'));
```

Change it to `required` to bind the correct error message to the check.

```php
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('workaround' => 'required'), array('required' => 'Wrong email and/or password.'));
```

Comment: Thank you. This might be not the most elegant solution like you said but I think it's better to do this for this simple task then implement custom validator.